# How do I center this Footer div?

Tags: html, css, footer

How do I center this footer? It keeps snapping to the bottom left. I want it bottom center. I'm losing my mind trying to figure this out.

## CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
#footer {
  position:absolute;
  bottom : 0;
  height : 40px;
  margin-top : 40px;
}
</style>
```

## HTML

```
<div id="footer">
   <a href="url">Footer Text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `margin: 0px auto;` on `#footer` -- Block elements are funky. (http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)

Comment: Try removing `position:absolute; bottom : 0;` and specifying an explicit `width` then continue with @CaseyFalk's suggestion.

Comment: I figured it out. added width: 100% and centered the <a> element

Comment: That may have solved your problem, but that doesn't answer your question. The `#footer` is still not centered; its *contents* are. Just fair warning. Glad it worked out. :)

Comment: @CaseyFalk `absolute` positioning removes the element from document normal flow and it changes the calculation of `auto` value of `margin` property. One option is to use percentage values for `left` and `right` properties like so: `position:absolute; bottom : 0; left: 20%; right: 20%;`. **[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/kirif/1/edit)**

Comment: Oh, duh; you are totally right, haha. My bad!